# how can i check if my android device is connected to the Desktop or not?

Tags: android, delphi, delphi-10.1-berlin

How can I know if my android device is connected to the computer or not?
In fact I'm developing an application with Delphi Berlin, and I want to close my app when I plug my device to the computer...

Comment: @Ben I see you linked it to a dupe but you didn't actually cast it as a close vote - just a comment...

Comment: @JerryDodge Yea sorry about that fixed it now.